# Unable to center div on page because of script tag

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I've been trying to develop a web application with Bootstrap 4.3.1 and the Spotify API, and all I wish to accomplish at this moment is to center a  element on the screen (vertically and horizontally) that contains the authenticated user's username. Apparently, I am unable to do this if the div is within a script tag - is there any way around this? I've included the relevant excerpt of my index.html file and my style.css file.

**Index.html**

```
<script id="user-info-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <div class="container h-100 d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="jumbotron my-auto text-center">
      <h1 class="display-4">Welcome, {{display_name}}.</h1>
      <h4 class="display-5">Select one of your playlists to get started.</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

**Style.css**

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

***EDIT***
Thank you all for the suggestions, but many of you have said that I shouldn't have  tags within my  tags, but I'm trying to follow an example created by Spotify. Their code has embedded JS in the index.html, and uses Handlebars like this:

*From their Index.html*

```
<script id="user-profile-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
      <h1>Logged in as {{display_name}}</h1>
      <div class="media">
        <div class="pull-left">
          <img class="media-object" width="150" src="{{images.0.url}}" />
        </div>
        <div class="media-body">
          <dl class="dl-horizontal">
            <dt>Display name</dt><dd class="clearfix">{{display_name}}</dd>
            <dt>Id</dt><dd>{{id}}</dd>
            <dt>Email</dt><dd>{{email}}</dd>
            <dt>Spotify URI</dt><dd><a href="{{external_urls.spotify}}">{{external_urls.spotify}}</a></dd>
            <dt>Link</dt><dd><a href="{{href}}">{{href}}</a></dd>
            <dt>Profile Image</dt><dd class="clearfix"><a href="{{images.0.url}}">{{images.0.url}}</a></dd>
            <dt>Country</dt><dd>{{country}}</dd>
          </dl>
        </div>
      </div>
    </script>
```

*At the bottom of their Index.html*

```
<script>
      (function() {

        /**
         * Obtains parameters from the hash of the URL
         * @return Object
         */
        function getHashParams() {
          ...
        }

        var userProfileSource = document.getElementById('user-profile-template').innerHTML,
            userProfileTemplate = Handlebars.compile(userProfileSource),
            userProfilePlaceholder = document.getElementById('user-profile');
    ...
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me',
                headers: {
                  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
                },
                success: function(response) {
                  userProfilePlaceholder.innerHTML = userProfileTemplate(response);

                  $('#login').hide();
                  $('#loggedin').show();
                }
            });
    ...
}
```

Comment: Why do you have divs inside a script tag?

Comment: I'm not even sure if it shows your inner script `div`! Since there you are not allowed to put a `div` inside `script` tags.

Comment: The script tag is used for javascript on the index.html page so you don't have to import a .js file, keep the div in your body and move it around using the .css file

Comment: @SMAKSS The divs are shown, it's just that I can't center them vertically. You're suggesting that I place the script tag within the divs?

Comment: @ShrewdStyle Are you saying that I don't need the script tag? The JS is embedded in the index.html file, and directly references the script tag with the id "user-info-template" (the one in my post).

Comment: the <div>s go in the <body></body> and any javascript you have goes in the <script></script>
If you have an external javascript file e.g. app.js, you would import this at the bottom of your <body> e.g. <script src="app.js"></script>

Comment: @TheFiveHundredYears I've just added an answer that might help you with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do this all on one page, without importing the app.js file, it will look like this using your divs

You can then insert any javascript you have between the script tags. If you want `{display_name}` to be a dynamic input you will need to create a function within the script tag referencing this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css" />
    <title>Spotify</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container h-100 d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div class="jumbotron my-auto text-center">
        <h1 class="display-4">Welcome, {{display_name}}.</h1>
        <h4 class="display-5">Select one of your playlists to get started.</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  <script>

  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can then move all of the divs and classes around in your css

Comment: I just edited my original post with the approach that Spotify took. I tried using Handlebars with this method, but it seems that their code (which is what I'm editing) requires the element being compiled to be a <script>.

Comment: @TheFiveHundredYears Spotify do not use standard HTML and CSS, hardly any company does these days which is why it looks like they are using HTML in their <Script> tag. Spotify uses Chromium Embedded Framework which i do not have much knowledge on, however if you only need to style your website and move things around, i would suggest my method of putting everything in the body tag and just use CSS to style it